# Using variables as keys in Object supplied to Object.assign

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am using Object.assign to get a new copy of an Object with added properties from another map. This is usually as simple as Object.assign(existingObject, {"new_key", "new_value"}), but when "new_key" comes in the form of a variable I have to use a temporary variable. How to avoid this?

A simple example:

```
function demo(inputKey, inputValue) {
    let data = {
        "existing_key": "existing_value"
    }
    let newData = {}
    newData[inputKey] = inputValue
    return Object.assign(data, newData)
}
//demo("new_key", "new_value")
//returns Object {existing_key: "existing_value", new_key: "new_value"}
```

Any tricks on how to avoid the temporary newData variable would be appreciated!

(I work a lot with reducers in Redux, this having great use for copying objects instead of mutating them.)

Comment: I guess there is a shortcut. If variable name that is containing value and key name are same, it accepts it. eg: `var a = "1", b="2"; var c = {a,b}` output: `{a:"1", b:"2"}`. [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in ES2015 using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
return Object.assign(data, {[inputKey]: inputValue})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can force a variable to be used as a key in object literals if you surround it with square brackets:

```js
function demo(inputKey, inputValue) {
    let data = {
        "existing_key": "existing_value"
    }
    let newData = {[inputKey] : inputValue}
    //newData[inputKey] = inputValue
    return Object.assign(data, newData)
}


console.log( demo('one',42) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already creating a new object **data**, no need to create another one.

```
function demo(inputKey, inputValue) {
    let data = {
        "existing_key": "existing_value"
    }

    data[inputKey] = inputValue;

    return data;
}
```